# Selecting all check-boxes on the registration form

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check all check-boxes on the registration form. But its giving **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.**

Here is the code which i have tried.

```
public class SelectCheckboxes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.wufoo.com/gallery/templates");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reg']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='stage']/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li[2]/a/b")).click();
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
        for (WebElement el : elements) {
            if (!el.isSelected()) 
                el.click();
            System.out.println("Checkboxes are selected");  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. But i think you missed out, there is a iframe in the registration form. Before doing any operations on the form, you need to switch control to the iframe and then perform your task.

Here is the working code for the same.

```
public class SelectMultipleCheckboxes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.wufoo.com/gallery/templates");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reg']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='stage']/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li[2]/a/b")).click();

        //Switch to Iframe
        WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wufooFormwu07ihv0jonvuv']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Field10']")).click();

        //Capturing all xpath in the list
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
        for (WebElement el : elements) {
            if (!el.isSelected()) 
                el.click();
            System.out.println("Checkboxes are selected");
        }

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();// Iframe is Switched to Main Again

        driver.close(); // Closes the current driver instance. 
        driver.quit(); // Closes all instances of browser.
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of your checkboxes are hidden and then try to add additional check

```
if (!el.isSelected() && el.isDisplayed()) 
    el.click();
```

But thats just suggestion, to be sure we need to see exact part of html code.